# Using include to dynamically point to HTML

Tags: python, html, jinja2

I want to point to a different HTML files based on a variable. I am using include in the following format:

```
{% include 'templates/case/{{cid}}/intro.html' %}
```

This throws an error:

```
TemplateNotFound: templates/case/{{cid}}/intro.html
```

Looking at this I know Jinja2 does not resolve the variable at runtime. The value of `cid = ABC` (ABC is a folder's name in the path), so I expected the total path to be:

```
templates/case/ABC/intro.html
```

If I use this resolved path directly in include it works.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 19):

At least in Jinja2 2.7.1 this works:

```
{% include 'templates/case/%s/intro.html' % cid %}
```

Answer (score 11):

Here's how to pass the code directly through include

```
{% include "templates/case/"+cid+"/intro.html" %}
```

Answer (score 6):

Found the answer in another Stack Overflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101864/dynamic-use-of-templates-in-jinja2?lq=1):

```
{% set path = 'templates/case/' + cid + '/intro.html' %}{% include path %}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could always compute the full path in view code and pass that down to the template, at that point, remove any quotes and curly braces around the variable.

While doing this, be wary of [path traversal attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal).

Comment: Thomas, thanks for the response. If you mean I pass the complete path in a variable: vid = 'templates/case/{{cid}}/intro.html' and then use it in the inclide .... {% include '{{vid}}' %}. I tried that ... this gives the same error ... TemplateNotFound.

Comment: @Utpal Did you try removing the '{{ }}' and just use {% include vid %}? I might be off, though, haven't used Jinja in a while, but I'd expect it to work similarly to django in that regard. You might want to check out this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101864/dynamic-use-of-templates-in-jinja2

Comment: Thanks a ton Thomas. Removing the '{{}}' works perfectly. However, I would check the 'path traversal attacks' that you warned me about.

Answer (score 0):

`{% module Template('templates/case/'+cid+'/intro.html') %}`