# jinja2 - how to expand variable in template name

Tags: jinja2

in jinja2 I'd like to do something as follows

```
{% for item in items %}
   {% include "template-{{item}}.html" %}
{% endfor %}
```

so that if items is ("a", "c", "d") the main template would include template-a.html, template-c.html and template-d.html

unfortunately I get the error that the template-{{item}}.html does not exist, the variable item does not get evaluated.

Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic use of templates in Jinja2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101864/dynamic-use-of-templates-in-jinja2)